# How can I slow down moving a rect in C++/SFML

Tags: c++, sfml

so here's the problem:
In my game, there is a functionality where when Player attacks enemy with his sword, the enemy is supposed to be knocked back slowly in the direction opposite from the player. In my current code, when the enemy is attacked, it moves, but it is so fast that it seems to teleport to the distance specified. Here is what I currently have:

```
//Player sword collides with enemy

        if (elapsed4.asSeconds() >= 0.05) //only 1 collision every .05 seconds

        {
            clock4.restart();

            counter1 = 0;

            for (iter30 = swordArray.begin(); iter30 != swordArray.end(); iter30++)
            {

                counter2 = 0;

                for (iter4 = enemyArray.begin(); iter4 != enemyArray.end(); iter4++)

                {

                    if(swordArray[counter1].rect.getGlobalBounds().intersects(enemyArray[counter2].rect.getGlobalBounds()))
                    {

                        soundSwordHit.play();

                        enemyArray[counter2].hp -= Player1.attackDamage;


                        if (enemyArray[counter2].hp <= 0)

                        {

                            enemyArray[counter2].alive = false;

                        }

                            //Move enemy upon damage

                            if (Player1.direction == 1)

                            {

                                enemyArray[counter2].rect.move(0, -50);

                            }

                            else if (Player1.direction == 2)

                            {

                                enemyArray[counter2].rect.move(0, 50);

                            }

                            else if (Player1.direction == 3)

                            {

                                enemyArray[counter2].rect.move(-50, 0);

                            }

                            else if (Player1.direction == 4)

                            {

                                enemyArray[counter2].rect.move(50, 0);

                            }


                        //enemy aggro
                        enemyArray[counter2].aggro = true;

                    }

                    counter2++;

                }

                counter1++;

            }

        }
```

i've tried using counters and timers within the loop but couldn't seem to get it to behave as I want it to. Just to clarify, I want the enemy to move n number of pixels per time t to simulate a smoothe moving. how can this be done? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't feel like I have enough knowledge to answer this question, but I'll try my best.

When designing a game ( a game that has smooth animation ) you need to think in terms of ticks, which is the time between this frame and the next one.
To calculate that, you need to take one time measurement at the beginning of your game loop, and another one at the end ( This is a well documented topic, please go read up on this ).

Because everything in a game happens in ticks, you cannot just move the character to a position and expect him to magically smooth out the movement over a bunch of frames; if you assigned a position to an entity, it will appear at that position in the next frame. ( I do not even think SFML has any features regarding animation ).

Let's assume this simple game loop.

```
while(running)
{
    // like i said, please read on measuring frame time, it's an extensive topic
    auto frametime = end - start;

    start = getTime(); // sorry, I do not remember what's the code for this
    readInput();

    // DO A LOT OF GAME STUFF

    end = getTime();
}
```

Having this frametime, you can already do a lot of very nice animation, let us say you wanted to move a character in a certain direction.

```
void move(Entity& entity, float x, float y)
{
    entity.move(x, y);
}

float moveByInX = 50.0f;
float moveByInY = 0.0f;

while(running)
{
    auto frametime = end - start;

    start = getTime();
    readInput();

    // DO A LOT OF GAME STUFF

    float deltaX = moveByInX * frametime;
    float deltaY = moveByInY * frametime;

    move(/* some entity */, deltaX, deltaY);

    moveByInX -= deltaX;
    moveByInY -= deltaY;

    end = getTime();
}
```

Now, bare in mind that, this is a really stupid design, these actions, frame measurements, animations --- SHOULD BE in nice objects, or functions at least, please read up
 a book on this kind of stuff, there is really a lot about game design, and how you should approach these problems. I recommend http://www.gameenginebook.com/ this.
And found two other resources that might prove useful to you https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Video_Game_Design/Programming and https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Guide_to_Game_Development.